# Ending an action started by an alarm

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I have an alarm manager that work partially well. It starts an action and what I really want is to stop this action at a later specified time. The class is given below.

```
public class MuteManagerClass {
    private Context mContext;
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    public MuteManagerClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }
    public void setAlarm(Calendar start, Calendar end, String card) {
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MuteBroadcastReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra("CARD", card);
        i.putExtra("end", end.getTimeInMillis());
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 3, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, start.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        //mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, start.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the alarm starts with the start calendar object. I want the action started by the alarm to end with the end calendar object. 
When the alarm starts, it mutes the phone, I want it to return to normal mode during the end calendar object.

Comment: Schedule another alarm at `end` that does whatever you need to do, possibly cancel the repeating alarm at `start`?

Comment: @ci_ thought of that, but was thinking there is a better way.